# in postgreSQL, we can add server(vm) in pgadmin so can we do the same using Fauxton in CouchDB

Tags: postgresql, couchdb

in Postgres if we have to do DB development work we can add server(VM) in pgAdmin and we can do almost everything on pgAdmin, pgAdmin is a GUI application.

so can we do the same in fauxton? adding server(VM) and do development work.

Answer (score 0):

Fauxton is also is a community-developed GUI for CouchDB however, you cannot add multiple servers as you can do in pgAdmin.

Having said that Fauxton gives you an option to create clusters from scratch using the [SETUP](https://couchdb.apache.org/fauxton-visual-guide/index.html#setup) tab and it will create a cluster setup for your development.

If you have installed CouchDB on localhost you can use `http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils` to open Fauxton start